# Connect to Socket from Outside Local Network

Tags: python, sockets, ipv6, ipv4, upnp

I'm trying to get a socket connection between two different terminals. When they are both on the same computer, or on a different computers on the same network (behind my home router), it works fine.

Here is a minimal example of the code I use. On the client side I enter the IP address I get from running `ipconfig` on the server, it works with both the `IPv4 Address` and the `Temporary IPv6 Address` (changing the corresponding flag of course)

SERVER

```
import socket

ip_address = ""
ipv6 = False  # True

PORT = 12345
STREAM = socket.SOCK_STREAM
if ipv6:
    FAMILY = socket.AF_INET6
    bind_args = (ip_address, PORT, 0, 0)
else:
    FAMILY = socket.AF_INET
    bind_args = (ip_address, PORT)


server_socket = socket.socket(FAMILY, STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_socket.bind(bind_args)
server_socket.listen()
unsecured_sock, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print("accepted from", client_address)
```

CLIENT

```
import socket


ip_address = "Entered from ipconfig or whatsmyip.com run from server"
ipv6 = False  # True

PORT = 12345
STREAM = socket.SOCK_STREAM
if ipv6:
    FAMILY = socket.AF_INET6
    bind_args = (ip_address, PORT, 0, 0)
else:
    FAMILY = socket.AF_INET
    bind_args = (ip_address, PORT)

sock = socket.socket(FAMILY, STREAM)
sock.connect(bind_args)
print("Connected!")
```

The problems arise when I take one of the computers out of the home network. As I don't have two standard networks I can access at the same time, I test this by connecting one of the computers to the internet via either the 4G on my phone or through a VPN. In either case, I then use the IP I get from `whatsmyip.com` ran from the server. I've tried all combinations of IPv4 vs IPv6 and whether the server or the client is behind my home router. In all cases it fails (note, I don't get a IPv6 address when the server is accessing the internet via 4G on my phone). In fact, I can't even `ping` or `tracert` the ip address of the server from the client terminal.

I suspect that I'm doing something very basic wrong, but I don't know what. I suspected it was to do with port forwarding, so I tried the following UPnP script

```
import upnpy

upnp = upnpy.UPnP()
devices = upnp.discover()
device = upnp.get_igd()
service = device.WANIPConn1

service.AddPortMapping(
    NewRemoteHost='',
    NewExternalPort=12345,
    NewProtocol='TCP',
    NewInternalPort=12345,
    NewInternalClient='192.168.0.136',  # Local server IP
    NewEnabled=1,
    NewPortMappingDescription='Test port mapping entry from UPnPy.',
    NewLeaseDuration=600)
print("added new port mapping")
```

which runs correctly but makes no difference. Am I right in thinking that this should be a non issue for IPv6 anyway? If it makes a difference, the provider for my internet says that my [connection is IPv6 and that I do not have a proper IPv4 public address](https://community.magenta.at/topic/5034-cannot-access-port-forwarding-connect-box/). Considering I want this to be portable and, eventually distributed, I'd rather avoid it be dependent on specific settings not accessible to the user.

Any pointers for a networking noob are most appreciated

Comment: rather than the address you get from a web site, what are the first two octets of the WAN address in your router?

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not sure I understand the question? If I log on to my router and look at the WAN IP settings I get
```IPv6 address : fe80::3a43:xx:yy:zz/64``` and    
```2a02:8382:xx:yy:zz:xx:yy:zz/128``` and 
```IPv6 default gateway : fe80::201:xx:yy:zz```

and nothing related to IPv4 at all. Is this what you meant?

Comment: "_I then use the IP I get from whatsmyip.com ran from the server._" Is that for IPv4 or IPv6? In any case, you may be running into an ISP problem because you have a residential network, and they all have a clause in the terms of use that forbid running a service to the Internet, and some ISPs actively block that. Also, port `12345` is actually registered to someone else, and you should not be using it, or any port in the User Ports (1024-49151) range without [IANA registration](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).

Comment: I used whatsmyip.com in both cases, how else am I supposed to find my external IP address? Thank you for the port, I thought 5 digits was considered fair game. I changed to 56789, but it made no difference. And I'm not trying to run a public service here, just get one computer that's monitoring an experiment talking to another one. Surely that's fair game?? It's less bandwidth (uploading and downloading) than someone playing MP games online.

Comment: But you are trying to host a server on your home network and provide a service to hosts on the Internet. Your ISP Terms of service will actually forbid it. In any case, to use IPv4, you must have an IPv4 WAN address on your router, otherwise it seems your ISP is using NAT, so you cannot forward a port and use IPv4. For IPv6, you use the Global IPv6 address assigned to your server, not the WAN address.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. If this is really blocked by my ISP, then so be it I guess, are there any alternatives for linking two computers live I should consider? Otherwise, I'm confused by your answer. Which IPv6 address should the client use to try and connect to the server? The one I get from ipconfig running on the server (and then there are three, IPv6 Address, Temporary Address and Link-local Address) or the one of the ones on the router WAN IP page (a short one ending /64 or a long one ending /128). Sorry for the basic questions, but I'm lost in a sea of jargon here.

Comment: Unlike IPv4 that uses NAT, for IPv6 you do not attempt to connect to the router WAN address. Every device should get a Global IPv6 address (the same as saying IPv4 public address), so you would connect to the Global address configured on your server. Be aware that the OS will default to random addressing with privacy extensions that change the address, so you want to configure the server to not do that. You need to ask about that on [su].